# Adding a picture to a report

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add a picture to a report I created in mvc. The report is actually an invoice so I want to make it look like a proper invoice with maybe the company logo next to the company name at the top of the report. I'm using report viewer to display the report.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the report designer, report data toolbox, add (embed) picture to `Images` node.
2. Place `Image` element onto report canvas and set source to be your previously embedded picture.